# Including {exp:channel:entries} within Freeform Notifications

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

Is it possible to include Channel Entry data within Freeform Email Notifications?
Either when using the Database Entry or the HTML Template method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this would be to use the `override_values` parameter:
https://docs.solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform/v2/templating/form.html#param-overridevalues

You can feed Freeform fields values at template level. What you'd want to do is create a hidden field that captures the Entry ID. Then override its (empty) value with the Entry ID:

`override_values:location="{entry_id}"`

You may need to have the form inside an embed in order to pass the Entry ID to it in time.

Then inside your email notification template, you should be able to feed a `{exp:channel:entries}` tag the ID you collected from that field, or perhaps you don't need to (if all you wanted was the ID or an Entry title, etc.

Comment: Thanks - I'll need to spent some time playing around with this, to get my head around it.
Ultimately, I'm trying to provide an editable EE Entry to the client Admin, which can be included within an Email Notification, in response to a Customer completing a Form.